# "This is something I am looking at removing."

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

I heard this sentence and I dont understand why it is correct:

> "This is something I am looking at"

...sounds fine to me as does:

> "This is something I am looking to remove."

Why is it correct?

Comment: *Looking to* means *to consider*, not *to behold*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, [*looking at*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/look_at) is an idiomatic phrasal verb that means *considering [doing something]*. It is a bit informal. Same thing with *looking to*. The difference is that *looking at* takes a present participle (-ing form) while *looking to* takes a bare infinitive.